# sample data from columns in synapse delta table

Tags: azure, apache-spark-sql, azure-synapse, delta-lake

I am trying to profile the data in a azure synapse delta table. One of the things I want to collect is a small sample of field values for each column.

I can do a column by column version and union the results. e.g.

```
SELECT '_ModifiedDatetime' AS column_name, string(collect_list(_ModifiedDatetime)) FROM (select DISTINCT _ModifiedDatetime from table) TABLESAMPLE (5 ROWS)
```

Note: The string function is in there to cope with unioning boolean lists

This is laborious. I was hoping someone had a more elegant way of doing this

Comment: Can you provide your sample input data expected results?

Comment: In the example above I would like to see something like this
column_name, sample_values
_ModifiedDatetime,[2017-10-05 03:29:43, 2017-10-15 09:47:35, 2017-10-14 22:17:17, 2017-10-15 12:26:51, 2017-10-05 04:02:24]

note: I have added the alias sample_values for the second column that I missed in the sql example above.